# What is the best way state management in flutter?

Tags: flutter

what is the best way state management in flutter?

Comment: I suggest correct way

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually there is no correct way to do it, but only different ways that vary on the application type and your style of coding.

The 2 most popular ways are **BLoC** and **Riverpod**. Do some research on both of them, learn both of them and see what fits your style.

I suggest you read Andrea Bizzotto's article about Riverpod: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-app-architecture-riverpod-introduction/

Comment: What about provider?

Comment: Yes that also works perfectly. Remember that provider is the foundational code for Riverpod. Riverpod gives you a well polished version of provider that has some added functionalities. You can read more about it here: https://codewithandrea.com/articles/flutter-state-management-riverpod/. BLoC instead is built upon data streams. this pattern as well has a great implementation with a lot of boiler plate code handled for you. Take a look at this package: 
https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_bloc or without the widgets part: https://pub.dev/packages/bloc